# Gauss' formula on positively oriented closed contour

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, volume, complex-integration

> Show for a positively oriented simple closed contour $C$ that the area of the region $G \subset{\mathbb{C}}$ enclosed by C is given by $\frac{1}{2i}\int_C \bar{z}\text{ d}z$. Use the Gauss' integral theorem.

So my steps towards solving the problem were as follows:

$$
\int_C \bar{z}\text{ d}z = \int_C (x-iy)\text{ d}(x+iy) = \int_C x\text{ d}x + y\text{ d}y + i\int_C x\text{ d}y - y\text{ d}x.
$$
So this can be written as the dot product of two vectors

$$
\int_C (x,y)\cdot(\text{d}x,\text{d}y)  + i\int_C (-y,x)\cdot(\text{d}x,\text{d}y) = \int_C (x,y)\text{ d}(x,y)  + i\int_C (-y,x)\text{ d}(x,y).
$$
Using the Gauss' integral theorem $\int_{\partial G} \vec{x}\text{ d}\vec{s} = \int_G \vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{v}\text{ d}A$ this leads to

$$
\int_C (x,y)\text{ d}(x,y)  + i\int_C (-y,x)\text{ d}(x,y) = \int_G \vec{\nabla}\cdot(x,y)\text{ d}A + i\int_G \vec{\nabla}\cdot(-y,x)\text{ d}A = \int_G 2\text{ d}A + i\int_G 0\text{ d}A = 2\cdot\text{vol}_2(G).
$$

So clearly this isn't the correct result. Where exactly is my misconception in the calculation?

I am thankful for any help.

Comment: Gauss's integral theorem wants the normal vector to the curve, not the tangent vector. For the tangent vector, use Stokes' theorem.

Comment: Okay, where exactly would this fact change the calculation?